# memcpy: starting address index of sun_path of unix socket

Tags: c, sockets, memcpy

So I have code as below for unix socket initialization

```
#define IETADM_NAMESPACE "IET_ABSTRACT_NAMESPACE"

struct sockaddr_un addr;

memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sun_family = AF_LOCAL;

memcpy((char *) &addr.sun_path + 1, IETADM_NAMESPACE, strlen(IETADM_NAMESPACE));
```

I got that `memcpy` copies IETADM_NAMESPACE starting at index address i.e. `&addr.sun_path + 1`.

My question is about the **`+ 1`** part of `&addr.sun_path + 1` expr.

Why is the address increased and string copied at there instead of just
`&addr.sun_path`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the **[man-page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html)**, there are three types of address that can be distinguished by the `sockaddr_un` structure: pathname, unnamed, and abstract.

The code you presented shows that after `memcpy`, the `sun_path` member will have its first byte as `'\0'`, because of the previous `memset`. Quoting the relevant part of the man-page:

```
*  abstract: an abstract socket address is distinguished (from a
   pathname socket) by the fact that sun_path[0] is a null byte
   ('\0').  The socket's address in this namespace is given by the
   additional bytes in sun_path that are covered by the specified
   length of the address structure.  (Null bytes in the name have no
   special significance.)  The name has no connection with filesystem
   pathnames.  When the address of an abstract socket is returned,
   the returned addrlen is greater than sizeof(sa_family_t) (i.e.,
   greater than 2), and the name of the socket is contained in the
   first (addrlen - sizeof(sa_family_t)) bytes of sun_path.  The
   abstract socket namespace is a nonportable Linux extension.
```

Comment: ok understanding that it is a abstract socket address. But now my next question is, why do we need abstract sockets, why not use regular unix socket. Any reason for same.

Comment: @drt: there are situations where your processes don't have permission to read & write to a common directory. The abstract namespace is an option in these cases. You create the socket using the abstract namespace, give it a name, and the kernel will keep this socket in memory. All the rest should work exactly the same way. The name acts as an identifier - two processes willing to communicate should refer to the same name.

Answer (score 1):

[man 7 unix](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html) has the answer:

```
Address format

[...]

abstract: an abstract socket address is distinguished (from a
          pathname socket) by the fact that sun_path[0] is a null byte
          ('\0').  The socket's address in this namespace is given by the
          additional bytes in sun_path that are covered by the specified
          length of the address structure.  (Null bytes in the name have no
          special significance.)  The name has no connection with filesystem
          pathnames.  When the address of an abstract socket is returned,
          the returned addrlen is greater than sizeof(sa_family_t) (i.e.,
          greater than 2), and the name of the socket is contained in the
          first (addrlen - sizeof(sa_family_t)) bytes of sun_path.  The
          abstract socket namespace is a nonportable Linux extension.
```